# Mysql getting data from tables with join

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

[image: test)]

I have created an sql query command to get data from these three tables , this command must help the user to search for a course from an search input , in this search input he can write the name of the course  or the name of the teacher who posted the course orthe key words of the course... through: name of the course(cours table) ,through name of teacher(user table), through key words(motCle table

i have wrote this command , but i have i m getting a wrong result while querying with key words ,

```
SELECT *
FROM cours c
JOIN users u ON u.id= c.userId
WHERE (c.nom LIKE '%name%' OR u.nom LIKE '%name%') OR EXISTS(
SELECT *
FROM cours c
JOIN intermots i ON i.coursId= c.id
JOIN motcles m ON i.motCleId = m.id
WHERE m.nom LIKE '%name%')
```

Comment: And what *is* your problem?

Comment: i need to search data using , course name(cours table) or teacher name(user table) or keywords (motcle)

Comment: All the matching users will be joined with all courses, not just the matching courses.

Comment: Use separate queries for matching users and matching courses, then combine with `UNION`.

Comment: when i write a keyword he display all the courses in the table course ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `EXIST` clause is not correlated. You want to know whether there exists key word for the row you are currently looking at. Remove the course table from the subquery and compare with the main query's course row instead.

```
SELECT *
FROM cours c
JOIN users u ON u.id= c.userId
WHERE c.nom LIKE '%name%' 
OR u.nom LIKE '%name%'
OR EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM intermots i
  JOIN motcles m ON i.motCleId = m.id
  WHERE i.coursId = c.id
  AND m.nom LIKE '%name%'
);
```

And here is an alternative with `IN` (where the subquery doesn't have to be correlated):

```
SELECT *
FROM cours c
JOIN users u ON u.id= c.userId
WHERE c.nom LIKE '%name%' 
OR u.nom LIKE '%name%'
OR c.id IN
(
  SELECT i.coursId
  FROM intermots i
  WHERE i.motCleId IN 
  (
    SELECT m.id
    FROM motcles m
    WHERE m.nom LIKE '%name%'
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Combine separate queries for each match with `UNION`

```
-- Match course name
SELECT c.*
FROM cours AS c
WHERE c.nom LIKE '%name%'

UNION
-- Match teacher name
SELECT c.*
FROM cours AS c
JOIN users AS u ON c.userid = u.id
WHERE u.nom LIKE '%name%'

UNION
-- Match keywords
SELECT c.*
FROM cours AS c 
JOIN intermots i ON i.coursId= c.id
JOIN motcles m ON i.motCleId = m.id
WHERE m.nom LIKE '%name%'
```